# How to compare 2 files and replace words for matched lines in file2 in bash?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

**FILE1** *(/var/widenet.jcml)* holds the LAN's server entries while **FILE2** *(hosts.out)* contains a list of IPs. My idea is to use FILE2 to search for IPs on FILE1 and update the entries based on matched IPs.

This is how FILE1 looks

```
[romolo@remo11g ~]$ grep -F -f hosts.out /var/widenet.jcml |head -2
2548,0,00:1D:55:00:D4:D1,10.0.209.76,wd18-209-76-man 91.widenet.lan,10.0.101.2,255.255.0.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NAS,ALL
2549,0,00:1D:55:00:D4:D2,10.0.209.77,wd18-209-77-man 91.widenet.lan,10.0.101.2,255.255.0.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NAS,ALL
```

While FILE2 is essentially a list of IPs, one IP per line

```
cat hosts.out
 10.0.209.76
 10.0.209.77
 10.0.209.158
 10.0.209.105
 10.0.209.161
 10.0.209.169
 10.0.209.228
```

Basically FILE2 contains 160 IPs which entries in /var/widenet.jcml are needed to be updated. In specific the word NAS on column 14 of /var/widenet.jcml needs to be replaced with SAS.

I came up with the following syntax, however instead of just replacing the word NAS for the matched IPs, it will instead replace every entries in FILE1 which does contain the word NAS, therefore ignoring the list of IPs from FILE2.

```
grep -F -f hosts.out /var/widenet.jcml |awk -F"," '{print$4,$14}' |xargs -I '{}' sed -i 's/NAS/SAS/g' /var/widenet.jcml
```

I spent hours googling for an answer but I couldn't find any examples that cover search and replace between two text files. Thanks

Comment: Does your file `hosts.out` contain the leading spaces shown in the question? Please extend your sample input to show both matching and non-matching lines of `widenet.jcml` and also show the expected result.

Comment: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} $4 in a {$14="SAS"}1' FS=, OFS=, file2 file1`

Comment: @WilliamPursell, tried your syntax, however while it does output the desired result, it does not update FILE1 with the result.

Comment: No, it does not update the file, because doing so is utterly against the unix philosophy. It is, however, trivial to overwrite the file with the desired data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming file2 doesn't really have leading blanks (if it does it's an easy tweak to fix):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{ips[$1];next} $4 in ips{$14="SAS"} 1' file2 file1
2548,0,00:1D:55:00:D4:D1,10.0.209.76,wd18-209-76-man 91.widenet.lan,10.0.101.2,255.255.0.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,SAS,ALL
2549,0,00:1D:55:00:D4:D2,10.0.209.77,wd18-209-77-man 91.widenet.lan,10.0.101.2,255.255.0.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,SAS,ALL
```

Comment: Ed, I also tried your command, though while it does output the desired result, it does not update FILE1 with the result. Thanks btw.

Comment: @mailman you didn't say you needed that in your question but with any command to update the input file is just `command file > tmp && mv tmp file`. Some commands (GNU sed, OSX/BSD sed, perl, GNU awk, ruby, etc. have options to do "inplace" editing but they just use a tmp file like I showed behind the scenes, they don't REALLY do the editing in place. Look for "inplace editing" in the man page for whatever command you use if you care to do that instead of specifying the tmp file manually.

Comment: This is best answer.

Comment: I truly appreciated your help Ed. You guys are life savers.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you only want to change NAS to SAS per IP address found in hosts.out?

```
while read line
 do 
 grep $line file1 | sed 's/NAS/SAS/g' >> results
 done < hosts.out
```

Comment: I just tried your recommendation, and while it does output the desired result, it does not update  FILE1. @alfred-e-noobman

Comment: Just updated but wasn't sure if you wanted to include the lines which were not found. Let me know if so.

Comment: Hey Alfred, I just realized it will add a new entry in FILE1 with the word SAS instead of NAS, however it wont delete the NAS one... Also, no if an IP in FILE2 is not found in FILE1 than that IP will need to be skipped. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: Ed's answer is better suited.